# Google script to test for selected menu item

Tags: menu, google-sheets, selection

A google script (.gs file) problem: I created a custom menu with several items in my google spreadsheet. When I click one of these menu items, I want to call a function (that part I've done) that can test for / determine the name of the menu item I clicked. This way, I can vary the logic based on which menu item I selected. A little help? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To enhance your question and increase the likelihood of getting some good advice - it would be good to show a snippet of the script you've already got working and the point where you can't get it to do what you want.  See [here for help creating a minimal complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).